# IIS 7 HTTP Redirect removing trailing slash

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server

We are running a server with IIS 7 and I've setup a 301 HTTP Redirect for an IIS Site, the forwarding URL is:

http://www.websitename.com/deliveries/

When IIS forwards on to this URL it removes the trailing slash and thus the web server handling the URL 'http://www.websitename.com/deliveries' fails to load the correct content because it's expecting a trailing slash (I have no control over this web server or site). Adding index.php to the URL works but I'd prefer it to work with the proper URL!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the URL Rewrite module? Here is an example to remove the trailing slash but I think it could be used to add it instead. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx